# Stretch a list-item full width depending on the amount of items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, widget

I have a footer where dynamically list-items can be added.
I would like to have the list-item stretch themselves over the given width of their container.

The whole thing is created in WordPress and the added list-items are widgets.
So this is what I have: 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzxpeztL/)

I can't give a single `.widget` a width of a certain percentage because this is determined by the amount of list-items displayed.

Hope it makes sense.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use  **Flexbox**

```css
ul{
  background:#000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li.widget{
   flex: 1;
   background:#FFF;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="widget">ITEM 1</li>
  <li class="widget">ITEM 2</li>
</ul>
```

Other one is **CSS Tables**

```css
ul{
  background:#000;
  display: table;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li.widget{
   background:#FFF;
   text-align: center;
   display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="widget">ITEM 1</li>
  <li class="widget">ITEM 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to work. I do need to test this cross-browser tho. Thnx!

Comment: You can see here how it behave when you append new `li` on click on `ul` https://jsfiddle.net/qzxpeztL/1/. Also http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Wow that last link is F-ing usefull. Thnx again

Comment: Due to the fact that table is supported cross browser I'll go with that!